# Exporting Variables From a Module

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I have a module A:

```
module A
  extend self
  attr_accessor :two, :four
  ONE = "one"
  @two = "two"
  @three = "three"
  @@four = "four"
  @@five = "five"
  def six
    "six"
  end
end
```

And I require it inside another file:

```
require 'a'
include A
p ONE     # => "one"
p two     # => nil
p A.two   # => "two"
p three   # => error
p four    # => nil
p five    # => error
p six     # "six"
```

It seems like any class variable either gives me an error or nil unless I specifically scope it with the module name. I thought using `include A` would prevent that. How do I export these class variables so that I can reference them directly as `two` instead of having to use `A.two`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you define variables at class/module level then it is a class instance variable not a instance variable. we are setting getter methods with `||=` because modules don't have initialize method;

```
module A
  ONE = "one"

  attr_writer :two

  def two
    @two ||= "two"
  end

  def three
    @@three ||= "three"
  end

  def three=(val)
    @@three = val
  end
end
```

Then you can use methods directly;

```
include A

p two
p three
two = 2
three = 3
p two
p three
```

Comment: missing `require_relative 'path/to/moduleA'` at the top of the second file